# Use system title bar in standalone windows in Chrome

Tags: chrome

I have turned on `⋮ > Settings > Use system title bar and borders` in Chrome.
Despite that Chrome does not use the system title bar on all windows.
Regular windows do have the system title bar but standalone windows don't.

Standalone windows sometimes open after you click a link or you can create shortcuts that open as standalone windows.

This is how you create a shortcut that opens as a standalone window:

1. `⋮ > More tools > Create shortcut …`
2. Check `Open as window`
3. Click `Create`

[image: Create shortcut dialog]

This is the system title bar on a regular window:

[image: system title bar]

This is a custom title bar Chrome uses for the standalone window:

[image: custom title bar]

Is there any way to get Chrome to use the system title bar on standalone windows?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=920768 Starring this bug report will help them at least not have that thick border and look closer to the native titlebar